# Flexibility with integration limits

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have an EE background and I am trying to integrate the equation for the voltage across an inductor. I am just playing around with the limits and want to check if all 3 of these equations below are correct or if I have made a mistake:

[image]

Are [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htKrH.png), [2] and [3] all correct?

Comment: Is $\int_{-\infty}^{0} V_L(\tau) d{\tau} = V_L(0)$ ?

Comment: @VedantChourey yes

Comment: I think I made a mistake in Eq 2, V_L(0) should be multiplied by 1/L as well.

Comment: [1] is correct if $i(-\infty) = 0$. [2] is wrong, as $\int_{-\infty}^0V_L(\tau)d\tau \ne V_L(0)$. It doesn't even have the right units. It is in fact $L i(0)$. [3] is correct.

Comment: @eyeballfrog If I multiply V_L(0) by (1/L) in [2], will it be correct then?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @alayoiskgfbfqhxjiw No. $(1/L)\int_{-\infty}^0 V_L(\tau) d\tau = i(0) - i(-\infty)$. This cannot be written in terms of $V_L(0)$. Also I was mistaken before by saying that integral was equal to $L i(0)$. It should have been $L[i(0)-i(-\infty)]$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Ah! That makes a lot of sense actually. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $a,b$, we have by the fundamental theorem of calculus that
$$
i(a) - i(b) = \frac{1}{L}\int_a^b V_L(\tau)d\tau.
$$
Let's compare this to your equations.

1. This is only true if $i(-\infty) = \lim_{t\rightarrow -\infty}i(t) = 0$.
2. This is never true even with the $1/L$ correction, as $V_L(0)/L$ has the wrong units. That term should instead be $i(0)$.
3. This is always true.